# Firebase Crashlytics invalid api KEY AndroidX Gradle 3

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Like many people, I am not able to add my application with Firebase Crashlytics. 
I followed all the steps from the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).

Also I previously checked and added my application to Firebase and everything is working fine.

My issue is the following:

```
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
```

I have the **google-services.json** file set correctly.. From the official documentation, it should works now without anything else to do..

**Edit - Solution**

Like I said in the comments, I found the issue. It's because of the Gradle version that I was using. I moved my project to support AndroidX and I was using the latest version 3.3+ but with this version the google-services.json file is not parsed during the build phase. It is resolved with the 3.2+ version.

From Firebase team, only stable version are working.

Comment: Hey @Sqrt Were you migrating from Fabric to Firebase or setting up Firebase Crashlytics in a new app?

Comment: I'm setting it to a new app.

Comment: Hmm, that should have worked then. Do you see any other references in your AndroidManifest.xml to a Crashlytics API key or fabric or crashlytics.properties file?

Comment: Nope everything is blank, I don't have anything anywhere. Juste the google-services.json file. But I have created a blank project and it's working fine. After some digging, I found that the google-service.json file is not parsed by my application... I don't have the step (:app:processDebugGoogleServices Parsing json file: /Users/mauricejouvet/Dev/BlankTestApp/app/google-services.json) But the gradle project files are the same for dependencies part...

Comment: Ok I found the issue, it's because of the Gradle version used.

Answer (score 2):

Is your project built to support instant apps (i.e. you have a base feature module, installable module, and instant app module)? I've been dealing with this exact error for the last day and a half, and what finally fixed it for me was adding `crashlytics { instantAppSupport true }` to the bottom of my gradle file for my base feature module. If you are built for instant apps, this might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you sure you have added the Crashlytics API Key in one of these files?**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Fabric Properties:

```
# Fabric properties file: app/fabric.properties
apiSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Nope, and I shouldn't do that. I didn't find any information regarding this properties file. I have the google-services.json file that contains my api key information. But I tried your solution, and it's not working. The api key is not valid.